# General solution to diffeerential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{4t}{1+3y^2}$$ is this the general solution?  $$y+y^3=2t^2+c$$  Can we continue to simplify it?

Comment: Yes. It is the solution. Well done :). You could solve for y, but that will look more ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Often the solution of a problem can be expressed on several forms. If the wording of the problem do not specify what kind of form is expected, your answer $y+y^3=2t^2+c$ is an implicit form which is a correct form of answer.

of course, other forms can be proposed :
$$t=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(y+y^3-c)}$$
which gives the inverse function $t(y)$. It is not specified in the wording of the question what function is wanted $y(t)$ or $t(y)$.

On can also solve $y+y^3=2t^2+c$ for $y$ and express the result on parametric form:
$$y=\frac{1}{3}z-\frac{1}{z}$$
$$z=\left(x\pm\sqrt{x^2+27}  \right)^{1/3}$$
$$x=\frac{27}{2}(2t^2+c)$$